# how to ascend or descend date in array using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and jquery.I want to arrange the date from items[] array to item1[] and item2[] array in ascending and descending order.

```
var items = ["01-Jun-17", "03-Jun-17", "03-May-17", "05-Jun-17", "05-Jun-17", "18-May-17"];

    Output:
    /*----logic for Ascending:::------ *\
    var item1=["03-May-17","18-May-17","01-Jun-17","03-Jun-17","05-Jun-17","05-Jun-17"];

    /*----- logic for  Descending:::------ *\
    var item2=["05-Jun-17","05-Jun-17","03-Jun-17","01-Jun-17","18-May-17","03-May-17"];
```

Comment: Great, do that. Research it. [Search for previous questions about it.](/help/searching) And make your title and question relate to one another. More in the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Normally I'd say that **if**, after thorough research, you still couldn't find it, post your code and a specific question. But even non-thorough research will find how to sort an array based on information derived from its entries.

Comment: What has this to do with trimming? Sounds like sorting?

Comment: Actually,there are name of months, and how to sort that, i am stucked here.

Comment: items.sort((a,b) => {return new Date(a).valueOf() - new Date(b).valueOf()});

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date -- convert the elements of your array to date objects, then sort THEM.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about sorting the array, then you could convert the strings to Date, and then apply sort function on it.

```js
var items = ["01-Jun-17", "03-Jun-17", "03-May-17", "05-Jun-17", "05-Jun-17", "18-May-17"];

items.sort((d1,d2) => new Date(d1) - new Date(d2) > 0);

console.log("Ascending: ",items);
console.log("Descending: ",items.reverse());
```

Comment: thanks, so easy logic.

Comment: but for second part(descend), still can't get the logic.

Comment: You can do `items.reverse()` to get the descending array. I just updated my answer with it.

Comment: items.sort((d1,d2) => new Date(d1) - new Date(d2) < 0);...this also works...i got it.

Comment: Yup that is also a valid way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have added both ascending and descending.  You can use javascript array's function sort.

```js
var items = ["01-Jun-17", "03-Jun-17", "03-May-17", "05-Jun-17", "05-Jun-17", "18-May-17"];

var items1 =jQuery.makeArray(items).sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a) < new Date(b);
});

var items2 = jQuery.makeArray(items).sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date(a) > new Date(b);
});
$("#div0").html(items);
$("#div1").html(items1);
$("#div2").html(items2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<lable>Original</lable>
<div id="div0"></div>
</br>

<lable>Asc</lable>
<div id="div1"></div>

</br>

<lable>Desc</lable>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: jQuery does not have a `.sort()` method. The method you're using is the `Array.sort()` method built into JavaScript...

Comment: @War10ck Thanks for the info.... :) Have updated